# Cant find class names when images added to DOM via appendChild

Tags: javascript, dynamic, lightbox

I created a lightbox and that dynamically adds images to the the light box using javascript. The issue that I am having is that when I add an image to the page and then I add a class to that image I can't seem to get the slider portion to work. I have narrowed it down to a few different things but here is the big problem. From what I am seeing when I run the code it tells me that there is no class named demo a.k.a cannot read property 'className' of undefined. This is related to the showSlides() function on the last line. I know that the issue is with dots in that piece of code. 
So I am thinking that what is happening here is that my other functions are getting called before my images are created and added to the page thus why i'm getting the error. So I have tried dozens of ways to make this work and I can't seem to come up with a solution. 
Is there a way to make this work or do I need to scrap this lightbox and start anew.

```
mymap.on('popupopen', function(e) {
var marker = e.popup._content;
let i;

for (var c in markerData.Markers[0]) {
            for (let h = 0; h < markerData.Markers[0][c][i]["Images"][1]['Regional Images'].length; h++) {
                let img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = markerData.Markers[0][c][i]["Images"][1]['Regional Images'][h];
                img.className = "demo";
                document.getElementById('column').appendChild(img);
}
        }
        else {}
    }
}
});

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

let prev = document.getElementsByClassName('prev');
let next = document.getElementsByClassName('next');
prev[0].addEventListener('click', function() { plusSlides(-1); } ); 
next[0].addEventListener('click', function() { plusSlides(1); });

function plusSlides(n) {
console.log('got here')
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}


function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
}
if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

I made the first change listed below but that doesn't solve the problem that I am having. I still get the same error of Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

Comment: `prev.addEventListener('click', plusSlides(-1));`  <-- wrong

Comment: There is an `else {}` without an `if`, a `HTMLCollection` has no `.addEventListener()` method, ... O.o

Comment: `prev[0].addEventListener('click', function() { plusSlides(-1); } ); next[0].addEventListener('click', function() { plusSlides(1); });`

Comment: I made this change but that didn't seem to fix it. Thanks though that answered another question. I may be able to use this to do it a different way. Any other insight you have?